# Navigate a Page with Page Source

Tags: html, autohotkey

I am looking for a way to write a script that uses the page source to navigate around the page. I haven't tried anything like this before, and everything I have found online relating to it just leaves me guessing. Does anyone know of a resource that could help a newbie accomplish this, or have anything to get me started?
For example, to post my question I would hit the "Post Your Question" button, which in the source is input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post Your Question" tabindex="120". Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tutorial, it explains the basic steps very good: https://jszapp.com/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-automatically-logs-in-to-any-website/